# Project a DateTime from an IQueryable to a string in a custom class

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, wcf-ria-services

I have this code running on the server part of my Silverlight application with WCF Ria Services:

```
public IQueryable<PersonePM> GetPersoneByCognome(string cognome)
    {
        return
            (from p in ObjectContext.Persone
             where p.Cognome.ToLower().Contains(cognome.Trim().ToLower())
             select new PersonePM
             {
                 Id = p.ID,
                 Cognome = p.Cognome,
                 Nome = p.Nome,
                 Sesso = p.IsMaschio == true ? "M" : "F",
                 StringaCognomeNome = p.Cognome + " " + p.Nome,
                 DataNascita = p.DataNascita == null ? DateTime.MinValue : p.DataNascita.Value,
                 LuogoNascita = (p.IsMaschio == true ? "Nato a " : "Nata a ") + p.Citta.Denominazione + " (" + p.Citta.Provincia.Trim() + ")",
                 CodiceFiscale = p.CodiceFiscale,
                 StringaNascita =
                    (p.IsMaschio == true ? "Nato a " : "Nata a ") + p.Citta.Denominazione + " (" + p.Citta.Provincia.Trim() + ")"
                 +
                 (p.DataNascita != null ?
                     (((p.DataNascita.Value.Day == 1) || (p.DataNascita.Value.Day == 8) || (p.DataNascita.Value.Day == 11)) ? " l'" : " il ") +
                     p.DataNascita.Value : string.Empty)
             });            
    }

public class PersonePM
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sesso { get; set; }
    public string StringaCognomeNome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascita { get; set; }
    public string LuogoNascita { get; set; }
    public string StringaNascita { get; set; }
    public string CodiceFiscale { get; set; }
}
```

Because of Italian language, I'd like to format where a person is born and when in a common language form for best users comprehension.
But the code above doesen't work because Linq-to-Entities is not capable of trasform a DateTime to a String (the whole story is a little different.. but let's say that for short); the error is thrown here:

```
StringaNascita =
                    (p.IsMaschio == true ? "Nato a " : "Nata a ") + p.Citta.Denominazione + " (" + p.Citta.Provincia.Trim() + ")"
                 +
                 (p.DataNascita != null ?
                     (((p.DataNascita.Value.Day == 1) || (p.DataNascita.Value.Day == 8) || (p.DataNascita.Value.Day == 11)) ? " l'" : " il ") +
                     p.DataNascita.Value : string.Empty)
```

The problem is well known and I found diffrent solutions but no one with projecting on a custom class like the one I use as a presentation model.
It's about a week I'm working on this problem and I haven't figured out a solution yet.
Any ideas?

Thank you!

**EDIT Jul 19 16.27GMT+1**

If I comment out this part

```
StringaNascita =
                    (p.IsMaschio == true ? "Nato a " : "Nata a ") + p.Citta.Denominazione + " (" + p.Citta.Provincia.Trim() + ")"
                 +
                 (p.DataNascita != null ?
                     (((p.DataNascita.Value.Day == 1) || (p.DataNascita.Value.Day == 8) || (p.DataNascita.Value.Day == 11)) ? " l'" : " il ") +
                     p.DataNascita.Value : string.Empty)
```

everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I solved the problem what I'm asking is: was that question too stupid no one reply or am I a sort of genius? I think it's the first! Thanks to every one helped me to solve the problem.

**Solution**

```
public class PersonePM
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sesso { get; set; }
    public string StringaCognomeNome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascita { get; set; }
    public string LuogoNascita { get; set; }

    /*Use the Getter to set the property based on other fields*/
    public string StringaNascita 
    {
        get
        {
            return LuogoNascita +
                (DataNascita != DateTime.MinValue ?
                     (((DataNascita.Day == 1) || (DataNascita.Day == 8) || (DataNascita.Day == 11)) ? " l'" : " il ") +
                     string.Format("{0:d MMMM yyyy}", DataNascita) : string.Empty);
        }
    }
    /* END of solution */

    public string CodiceFiscale { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<PersonePM> GetPersoneByCognome(string cognome)
    {
        return
            (from p in ObjectContext.Persone
             where p.Cognome.ToLower().Contains(cognome.Trim().ToLower())
             select new PersonePM
             {
                 Id = p.ID,
                 Cognome = p.Cognome,
                 Nome = p.Nome,
                 Sesso = p.IsMaschio == true ? "M" : "F",
                 StringaCognomeNome = p.Cognome + " " + p.Nome,
                 DataNascita = p.DataNascita.HasValue ? p.DataNascita.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
                 LuogoNascita = (p.IsMaschio == true ? "Nato a " : "Nata a ") + p.Citta.Denominazione + " (" + p.Citta.Provincia.Trim() + ")",
                 CodiceFiscale = p.CodiceFiscale,
             });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you get the raw data from the database, and then perform the string conversion later.

To force a conversion from `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` you can use [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) - so you'd have:

```
var dbQuery = from data in source
              where stuff
              select simple-projection;

var clrQuery = from data in dbQuery.AsEnumerable()
               where client-side-filters
               select client-side-projection;
```

if you see what I mean.

Note that `AsEnumerable()` really just changes the compile-time type of the expression, so that the other bits of the query are performed using `Enumerable.*` instead of `Queryable.*`.

Comment: Thank you Jon for replying so quickly.
I thought it was something I've still tried but I tried again "just in case". The code:
    public IQueryable<PersonePM> GetPersoneByCognome(string cognome){
    var rawQuery = from p in ObjectContext.Persone
    where p.Cognome.ToLower().Contains(cognome.Trim().ToLower())
    select p;
    var projectedQuery = from p in rawQuery.AsEnumerable()
       select new PersonePM{(Projection)};
    return projectedQuery.AsQueryable();
        }
This throw a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Angelo: Returning `IQueryable<T>` here would give the wrong impression anyway - any additional filters etc put on your returned query would occur in the .NET process. It's not obvious why your modified version is throwing an exception - you should edit your question to give that code and more details about the stack trace of the exception. It could be any number of things.

Comment: Jon, I didn't understand what you mean until now. You were suggesting of doing the projection on the client side and not on the server.
But the problem is I want packed only data I need and throw away the useless data without they traveled on the network.
I saw many solution about this problem when the projection is only a DateTime data and not a complex type.

Comment: A binary DateTime is generally smaller than its string representation.

Comment: @Angelo: Stephen is exactly right. I'd expect a `DateTime` to take a very small amount of space on the wire - it's just a number, after all.

Comment: Sorry guys but I don't follow you.
What's the matter about the ammount of space needed.
The issue is I can't write something like: BornString = DateOfBorn.Value.ToShortString() because Linq-to-Sql can't convert it.